# Multiple Build Errors: 'X' does not exist in namespace 'Y'

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

We have a program that has been idle in development for about 2 months.  The last time we worked on it, everything worked fine.  I opened it in Visual Studio 2015 to make a couple of minor changes and when I rebuilt it for the first time about 30 errors popped up in the build.  The errors are all problems in finding resources:

> The tag 'ResourceControl' does not exist in XML namespace 'clr-namespace:NewScheduler.Controls;assembly=NewScheduler'.

This is repeated for various controls throughout all of the projects in the solution.  All of these worked the last time that we built the project, and no changes have been made in the references.

An example of one that used to work and is now throwing an error, in a user control:

```
<UserControl  ...
             xmlns:classes="clr-namespace:NewScheduler.Classes"
             >

    <UserControl.Resources>
        <classes:HoursToHeightConverter x:Key="HoursToHeightConverter"/>
        ...
    </UserControl.Resources>
```

All of the errors point to the same namespace.  The latest changes were not made in this namespace.

I have followed many steps that I have found here on Stack Overflow:

- gone to solution configuration management, checked and unchecked the build
- cleaned the entire solution.
- cleaned each project individually
- removed and re-added the reference to the problem project
- deleted the .suo file

At a loss right now.

Comment: It is not likely you will be able to get an answer here. You haven't provided a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem, nor is it clear that you would be able to. Assuming you understand how XAML uses XML namespaces and how the `clr-namespace` syntax works, you'll just need to double-check everything, and figure out where the missing types went. If you don't understand how all that works, that's your first step: make sure you do.

Comment: understandable.  I am very stumped at this point thought, and this is the best resource that I know of.  All references and types are where they should be, and where they have been for the 3 years that we have run this program.  What I am hoping is that someone else has seen something similar to this and has solved it using something other than what I have already attempted.

Comment: _"All references and types are where they should be"_ -- I doubt it. I mean, I obviously can't say for sure, since I don't have access to your development environment and code. But it's _highly_ unlikely you'd be getting that error if in fact everything was where it's supposed to be. Indeed, the crux of this problem is almost certainly going to turn out to be something that changed, but which you did not realize had changed. Right now, you're operating under the impression that everything is exactly as you left it two months ago, but it's very likely your impression is wrong.

Comment: Find out how your impression is wrong, and you be very close to solving the problem, if not have the solution in hand.

Comment: Every single error is roughly the same? Post the bottom-most error, sometimes it's the first error that prevent "ResourceControl" from being compiled, which breaks everything else in your project that uses it.

Comment: Peter, I have been looking into things that may be different.  The main reason why I believe that things are the same is that the project has not been touched -- because the developer of this project left the company.  No-one else here has touched it since then -- he published one last build on the day he left, so I know it was working then. I logged into his old computer --using his sign-in -- and did a rebuild all to double check everything and this happened.  I agree that something is wrong / changed, but am struggling to find a direction to look at this point.

Comment: Jai -- every single error is the same format:  Tag 'x' does not exist in namespace 'Y' a total of 30 errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We did find out the error.  Peter was correct. Nothing had changed on our end (that we knew of), but our programmer had been using a personal MS office account and when he left the company he deactivated the software on his computer at our office.  This removed a dll that the project depended on.